# JS and CSS doesn't load on local

Tags: javascript, html, css, local

sorry for the newbie question, but I started my programming adventure two months ago.
I have a doubt: a client commissioned me to demo a website (so it would only work offline) and I am making the design.
Many pieces are reusable, so I have created elements via javascript to be called in the code.
The problem is that while if I start the page from the VS Code live server everything loads fine, while if I in the folder statically open an html file neither the CSS nor the JS loads. I think it is a problem with how they are linked.
My idea was to deliver a folder with all the files and I imagined that he clicking would be able to see all the components and navigate through the pages. Any solutions?

Here's an example on how I linked those JS files (it works on live server)

```
<script src="/components/card.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have file in local in the correct path?

Comment: `"I imagined that he clicking would be able to see all the components and navigate through the pages"` - does he ( your client ) have a webserver setup? Has he copied your files to the correct locations in said webserver (if it exists) in order that the paths in your code will exist? Or do you hope that he will be able to run the code using the filesystem rather than proper urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs starting with a single `/` are absolute paths.

They are calculated by taking the current URL and completely replacing the path.

If you start with `http://localhost/index.html` then you get `http://localhost/components/card.js`. Your HTTP server will then resolve that to something like: `/home/user/work/project/components/card.js` and all is good.

If you start with `file:///home/user/work/project/index.html` then you get `file:///components/card.js` … which is wrong.

---

There are a couple of approaches you can take with this.

My preferred one is to treat websites as **things that should be accessed over HTTP**. There are lots of restrictions if you don't use HTTP, and these kinds of URLs just break. The simple solution is to **use a web server**.

Another approach is to use relative paths, in which case you need to be explicit about where you link to in terms of directories.

Going from `$PROJECT/index.html` to   `$PROJECT/components/card.js` needs you to link to `components/card.js` **but** going from `$PROJECT/example/index.html` to   `$PROJECT/components/card.js` needs you to link to `../components/card.js`. It's a lot harder to maintain.

---

> My idea was to deliver a folder with all the files and I imagined that he clicking would be able to see all the components and navigate through the pages.

How you deliver to a client will depend on what you negotiate with them.

In very broad terms, however, they are either going to be non-technical (in which case you should deliver them a URL and be responsible to organising the hosting of the final site) or technical (in which case they should be able to handle an instruction to test the code on a web server).

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I have to be honest: I was already trying this solution but it didn't seem to work. Your solution, however, made me persist and after restarting the pc everything worked

Thank you again, I can finally move on!